# PHP - Is there PostgreSQL equivalent to mysqli_next_result()

Tags: php, postgresql, mysqli

I'm converting some PHP from using MySQL to PostgreSQL. Is there an equivalent function for PostgreSQL to mysql_next_result()?

Comment: Do you mean pg_get_result()? http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-get-result.php

Answer (score 0):

You can execute multiple SQL statements with a single `pg_query` call if they are separated by semicolon, but it looks like you can only get the result of the last query in that case.

Change the code to execute one statement at a time if you want the results.

Answer (score -2):

I don't use MySQL so assuming you're iterating through a result set a common pattern would be:

```
$conn = pg_connect(....);
$rs = pg_query_params($conn, $sql, $params);

while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
  // Do stuff with the row.
}
```